# My PDF shows up with strange colors when uploaded onto a website

Tags: pdf

I have a reduced-size PDF that looks completely normal on the desktop, but when placed on a website the bottom half of the PDF has a pinkish color over it, and makes some items in the PDF have light greenish/teal colors.

[image]

[image]

This is a piece of it, the first image is an image of the PDF when viewed as a file on the computer, any ideas? (The top half of the PDF looks fine no matter what).

Comment: What are you using to "place" the PDF on your website?

Comment: A CMS file manager(Concrete5)

Comment: Sounds like either a corrupt upload/download or an issue with the browser PDF plug in -- web browsers don't support the viewing of PDFs natively.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because you've saved your PDF in the CMYK color space (I've seen this a lot before).

Open your PDF, convert it's color mode to RGB, and then save it again.  That will solve your problem.